# How to move a question from one page to another in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I have two pages in a Google Form. I have created a question in Page 1, and now I want to cut and paste it out of Page 1 and put it into Page 2. However, using drag and drop doesn't seem to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, if you duplicate the question you want to move, you can drag the duplicate copy of the question to the other page (and then delete the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Anything new you insert shows up at the end of your form. If you add a page break, it will show up at the end of your form. Go ahead and create the page break, even though it shows at the bottom of the form.

After you duplicate the questions you want to use on the second page, they will remain on the same page as the first set of questions. Instead of moving the questions down to the second page, you will need to move the page break up above the questions...the questions will then show up on page 2 of the form.